# If I change the permalink settings in wordpress, will this affect my previous blog posts (ie. already published blog posts)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking to change from `/blog/post-name/` to `/blog/2015/10/20/sample-post/`. Would this change the permalink for previously published posts? Or would it only apply to future posts?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Put some code or some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This rewrite rule would apply to all posts...

The chosen permalink structure is stored in the `wp_options` database table, as the `permalink_structure`.

This structure is used to rewrite all permalinks (past, present, and future).

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not affect any of your post weather they are previous posts or upcoming. Wordpress will handles it using rewrite rules.

If your previous posts were indexed in search engine then it will show the previous URL, but as any user clicks on it, it will goes to your new URL till the indexing of your new URLs.

Your web pages will not affect by changing the permalink structure.

Comment: If the OP is asking about changing the permalink structure in the admin panel, then he is in fact changing the rewrite rules for how posts are handled and it will change all posts past, present, and future.

It also will not reliably handle redirects, the [system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical) that does that is temperamental at best.